# During handling of the above exception ([Errno 13] Permission denied: 'new1234567.csv'), another exception occurred

Tags: python, pandas, linux

I am trying to create a csv file using pandas in the AWS EC2 instance(Linux OS) using the below code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(listlead)
df.to_csv('new1234567.csv')
```

I am getting an error 'Permission denied' from the server. But when I run it on the local system(Windows OS) it was working fine.

I try to change the name of the file but the error continues to exist.
I try to delete the file but it said file does not exist.
Can someone give me a solution for this problem and tell why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you don't have permission to create a csv file in the folder you're working in, on the server.

When you run`df.to_csv('new1234567.csv')`, it looks for a file named `new1234567.csv` inside the current directory, and if it doesn't exists, it tries creates it - which is also the reason you're not able to delete it: it doesn't let you create it in first place.

Go with a terminal inside the working directory in which you're trying to create the file (same directory of your script, in this case), and run `sudo chmod 700 .` This will add read, write and execute permissions to the current user only.

Now your script should be able to create, read and write new files in the directory.

Comment: No it did not work. Rather I got forbidden to access this file error.

Comment: Make sure you're typing the commands properly and that you're working in the correct directory. I just re-tested the commands and they do the job.
Proof:

`cd test `, 
`touch t`, 
_cannot touch 't': Permission denied_ , 
`sudo chmod 700 .`, 
`touch t`, 
This creates the `t` file correctly

Comment: I was able to create the t file with chmod 777 by giving permission to all. But till I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried running the script as sudo?

Comment: Yes and still not working.

Comment: I'm sorry but the whole process seems to be working for me, even writing the file with pandas, as you did in the question's code. Could you please give me more information on what you're doing? Please edit the quesiton adding each command you run starting from printing the working directory, and the command you use to run python. For each one, the output given.

Comment: Thank for answer my question. The issue was that I did not specify a specific path thinking that the file will get created in the current folder. But in linux the function try to create the file in root folder which is why the permission was denied. I created a new folder and give read write permission and specified that path in the code and it worked. Thanks.